# Binding mouse buttons with Logi Options+ for Windows Photos in full screen

Tags: windows, logitech-mouse

Windows Photos does not bind mouse Back/Forward buttons to next/previous image even though the left/right arrow keys work that way, but with a Logitech mouse you can use Logi Options+ to assign keyboard shortcuts on a per-app basis, so that seemed like a solution. However, when trying that with Photos, it only works when the app is not in full screen mode; in order to have those bindings for the app when in full screen, they must be set globally, which is not ideal. Is there a workaround for this?